# How redirect user to original url after create account and login?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

My issue is related with redirect after login but... my steps are:

1. user is on page with report and should login
2. go to login page should click on link "create account"
3. go to create account page
4. go to login page (after successful created account)
5. go to page with report with clean cache [without clean cache user still see that should login to download]

I'm losing my referrer page because after login user go to creates an account and then comes back to login. Any idea how to do this in wordpress/jquery/php ?

```
  if ($('.reports_form--registration').length) {
    ReportsForm.init($('.reports_form--registration'))
  }

  if ( $('.reports_form--login .report_form__redirect_to' ).length ) {
    var referrer  = document.referrer || ''
        home_link = window.location.origin
        create    = "create";

    if ( referrer.indexOf(CG_EXTUSR.home_url) > -1 ){
      $('.report_form__redirect_to').val( referrer );
    }

    if ( referrer.includes(create) ){
      $('.report_form__redirect_to').val( referrer + '/?clean_cache');
    } else {
      $('.report_form__redirect_to').val( referrer );
    }
  }
```

Comment: save the current url in session when they click login or create account

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the [WordPress `user_register` hook.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

```
function redirect_to_login( $user_id ){
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'redirect_to_login', 25 );
```

[`wp_login_url` also accepts a param](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) for a redirection after logging in, so you could use that to redirect to a clear cache page.

But depending on the caching plugin you're using it should be possible to set the reports page to be ignored from caching for logged in users.